# VS 2010 C# ReportViewer why is data not showing in column?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, datasource, reportviewer

I have old C# project that was .Net 2.0 using Report Viewer 8.0.50727.42 and I imported it into visual studio 2010, changed it to use .Net 3.5 and Report Viewer 10.0.40219.1 and everything appears to work fine except in one report one of the columns of data shows #Error instead of the value.

The database is a SQL compact 3.5 SDF file.

What it is, I have a list of Event Classes I want to show and each Event has an attribute of the class EventType.

So for the Type column I have the following as the expression in the rdlc:

```
=Fields!EventType.Value
```

And in my EventForm I've placed a breakpoint at the DataSources.Add() function. It looks like this:

```
ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource("Manager_Base_Event", bindingSource);
reportViewer.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);
```

When it breaks there, I can see the data I want in the stack but as I say it shows #Error and unfortuantely, as far as I can see, it doesn't give me a reason for that.

I've tried putting [Serializable()] on the Event and EventType class and it didn't help.

Does anyone know how I could better debug this to get the exact reason why the data isn't showing or maybe already know why it's not showing?

What confuses me is I'm doing same sort of thing with other classes in the other reports and there is no problem whatsoever so I'm not sure why this isn't working.

If it matters I have an attribute on the EventType class of [TypeConverter(typeof(EventTypeTypeConverter))]

I thought that may be related but I couldn't find anything to confirm this could cause problems.

Comment: What data type that field has? Is this nullable type or not?

Comment: Have you tried to display data from that DataSource in some other way? In DataGridView or other controls?

Comment: I've changed it to explicitly call the ToString method and still get the error. After realising the "Just my code" box was ticked, I unticked that and see I'm getting: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException_FieldError occurred which is dying at Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.OnDemandReportObjectModel.FieldImpl.get_Value(). So I'm going to look from there.